# How to execute a shell command on the server side within javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to run a shell command on the server side when a client triggers an event. Is it possible with javascript?

Comment: You need to connect to the server, so javascript alone cannot do it.

Comment: maybe nodejs? nodejs is JS :)

Comment: client $.ajax -> server, server -> triggers shell command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with client-side JavaScript.

Althought it's not really your question, you could do it if you were using NodeJS server-side (http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).